# Character encoding in jspx

Tags: character-encoding, jspx

I have a jspx page containing some German character. But on rendering in browser, it is throwing the below error:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:684)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:405)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(XMLEntityScanner.java:1416)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2793)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:172)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:226)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:193)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pmt.details.details_002dtemplate_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(details_002dtemplate_jspx.java:97)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.pmt.details.details_002dtemplate_jspx._jspService(details_002dtemplate_jspx.java:62)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.DefinitionAttributeRenderer.write(DefinitionAttributeRenderer.java:56)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f1(default_jspx.java:155)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.layouts.default_jspx._jspService(default_jspx.java:84)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Also I have tried the encoding and charset with ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 both like shown below:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

But by default, it is picking UTF-8 Reader as can be seen in stacktrace.

Is there any other way to set encoding ISO-8859-1???

Comment: What happens when you switch page encoding to UTF-8? Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

please test

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
```

in top of each jspx  page ,also don't forget to save project as utf-8,on eclipse right click on project folder and in resource choose Text file encoding as UTF-8